# Unable to update drupal 8.4.3 to 8.4.5 using composer

Tags: drupal-8

I'm following this guide to "[Update core via Composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer-option-4)" and I have my backups. The document says to run

```
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
```

When I do, I get:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::preAutoloadDump
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::ensureHtaccess
```

drush core-status says I'm on version 8.4.3, so I expected the composer update command to move me to 8.4.5.

Later the document says to "Review the *status report* page for errors" and the only error listed is that I need to be on version 8.4.5

There must be something missing from the update documentation, and I can't figure out what it is.

Edit: Thanks Robb Davis, I tried:

```
rm -rf vendor
rm composer.lock
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
```

That gave me no change -- leaving me with an 8.4.3 installation.

I tried `composer require drupal/core:8.5` which gave me:

```
$ composer require drupal/core:8.5
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for drupal/drupal dev-master -> satisfiable by drupal/drupal[dev-master].
    - don't install drupal/core 8.5.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - Installation request for drupal/core 8.5 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.5.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Nothing in that message makes any sense to me. So I'm still lost.

Comment: A year later and I was managing to struggle by with updates until the latest one. I'm supposed to update from 8.6.10 to 8.6.12, and 'composer outdated' shows that. But composer update drupal/core says Nothing to install or update.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to update 8.5 to 8.6. Dumping the core and vendor folders in addition to the `composer.lock` file did not work for me.

I was able to resolve this issue by removing the `core/composer.json` line from the `merge-plugin` `include` array and running `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies`.

My `merge-plugin` key in the `composer.json` file in the docroot looks like:

```
"merge-plugin": {
      "include": [],
      "recurse": true,
      "replace": false,
      "merge-extra": false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes this is kind of foobar. There is a blog post about it here:
https://orkjern.com/updating-to-drupal-85-with-composer

The solution in the blog didn't work for me but a solution in the comments did:

1. Delete your vendors directory
2. Delete your .lock file
3. Run composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies

This will rebuild / redownload everything but it seems to work and updates properly to 8.5 (the most recent stable version of core).

Comment: Having no luck with that either Robb, but thank you for the pointer. (What is webflo?) The composer update command gives me:- Installation request for drupal/drupal dev-master -> satisfiable by drupal/drupal[dev-master].
    - don't install drupal/core 8.5.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - Installation request for drupal/core 8.5.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.5.0].